# diagonal movement to a enemy in pygame

Tags: movement, pygame

I spent a long time trying to make the diagonal movement in the form of code but I don't know how to write it. the code I have so far is almost complete but it is missing the pixelart that I will add later

````
import pygame

class game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
        self.square = pygame.Rect((250, 250), (100, 100))
        self.leftframe = pygame.Rect((40, 40), (10, 510))
        self.rightframe = pygame.Rect((550, 40), (10, 520))
        self.frameup = pygame.Rect((40, 40), (520, 10))
        self.framedown = pygame.Rect((40, 550), (510, 10))

        self.enemy = pygame.Rect((100, 100), (50, 50))
        self.enemy2 = pygame.Rect((450, 300), (50, 50))
        self.enemy3 = pygame.Rect((300, 500), (50, 50))
        self.directionenemy = 1
        self.directionememy2 = 1
        self.directionenemy3 = 1

    def play(self):
        self.clean_screen()
        self.draw_borders()
        self.hear_events()
        self.draw_square()
        self.move_and_draw_enemy()
        self.move_and_draw_enemy2()
        self.move_and_draw_enemy3()
        self.check_for_contact()
        self.check_for_contact2()
        self.check_for_contact3()
        self.update_screen()

    def move_and_draw_enemy(self):
        self.enemy.move_ip(self.directionenemy, 0)

        if self.enemy.colliderect(self.rightframe):
            self.directionenemy = -1
        
        if self.enemy.colliderect(self.leftframe):
            self.directionenemy = 1

        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 0, 0), self.enemy)
    
    def move_and_draw_enemy2(self):
        self.enemy2.move_ip(0, self.directionememy2)

        if self.enemy2.colliderect(self.frameup):
            self.directionememy2 = 1

        if self.enemy2.colliderect(self.framedown):
            self.directionememy2 = -1
        
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (10, 50, 255), self.enemy2)


    def move_and_draw_enemy3(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (50, 50, 50), self.enemy3)


    def check_for_contact(self):
        if self.square.colliderect(self.enemy):
            self.directionenemy = 0
        elif self.directionenemy == 0 and not self.square.colliderect(self.enemy):
            self.directionenemy = 1

    def check_for_contact2(self):
        if self.square.colliderect(self.enemy2):
            self.directionememy2 = 0
        elif self.directionememy2 == 0 and not self.square.colliderect(self.enemy2):
            self.directionememy2 = 1

    def check_for_contact3(self):
        if self.square.colliderect(self.enemy3):
            self.directionenemy3 = 0
        elif self.directionenemy3 == 0 and not self.square.colliderect(self.enemy3):
            self.directionenemy3 = 1

    def clean_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    def draw_borders(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (72, 47, 125), self.leftframe)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (72, 47, 125), self.rightframe)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (72, 47, 125), self.framedown)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (72, 47, 125), self.frameup)

    def hear_events(self):    
        for e in pygame.event.get():
                if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    self.move_and_draw_square(e.key)

    def move_and_draw_square(self, key):
        if key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.move_square(-1, 0)
            if self.square.colliderect(self.leftframe):
                self.move_square(1, 0)

        elif key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.move_square(1, 0)
            if self.square.colliderect(self.rightframe):
                self.move_square(-1, 0)

        elif key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.move_square(0, -1)
            if self.square.colliderect(self.frameup):
                self.move_square(0, 1)

        elif key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.move_square(0, 1)
            if self.square.colliderect(self.framedown):
                self.move_square(0, -1)

        elif key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()

    def move_square(self, x, y):
        self.square.move_ip(x * 10, y * 10)

    def draw_square(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0, 204, 0), self.square)

    def update_screen(self):
        pygame.display.update()

pygame.init()
game = game()

while True:
  game.play()
```
````

Comment: What have you tried? What is the issue?

Comment: yes, i tried but i dont know how to do a diagonal movement with the third enemy